# Difference between creating a "new object" and "Class objectname"

Tags: java, class, object

Say for example I have a class called Phone.

What is the difference between:

```
Phone p;
```

and

```
Phone p = new Phone(200) //(200 is the price of the phone).
```

and

```
new Phone(200)
```

I've googled and even tried it on Eclipse but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Phone p;` only declares a reference handler `p` which doesn't point anywhere (it is a not initialized and cannot be used until you assign something to it [thanks @Anthony]).

`Phone p = new Phone(200);` declares a reference handler `p` which points to a newly created `Phone` object (initialized with `Phone(200)`).

`new Phone(200)` creates a new `Phone` object, but since no reference to it is stored anywhere, it becomes immediately eligible for garbage collection (unless its constructor stores a reference somewhere, that is).

<sub>(Note that in Java, all "variables" whose type is a reference-type are really reference handlers. Only variables of value-type contain values directly. Since `Phone` is a reference-type (it's a `class`), `Phone p` is always a "reference to a `Phone`".)</sub>

Comment: For the third bit: assuming there's no "leaking this" in the constructor :)

Comment: @KublaiKhan: Yes, I said that. The constructor could call upon some Mighty Singleton to store a reference, for instance :-) .

Answer (score 5):

The first snippet only declares a variable `p` with a given type `Phone`. You have not created any object, only a variable.

The third instantiates a new `Phone` object (which is not assigned to a variable).

The second combines the two, the declaration and instantiation, into a single line of code.

```
Phone p; // declaration of variable 
p = new Phone(200); // instantiation of object, assigned to variable 

Phone p = new Phone(200); // declaration and instantiation in a single line
```

For `p` to be used, you need to instantiate it (or otherwise initialize it). The declaration itself is not useful. In a local (a variable declared inside the scope of a method), it is illegal to use it without first initializing it. If it's a class-level member, then it will simply be a null pointer when you try to access any of its member functions.

Comment: Doesn't *every* variable in Java get initialized? The first `p` should have a well-defined value.

Comment: @KerrekSB, class members are initialized to default values (null for references), but locals are not initialized (as far as the compiler is concerned) and must be before first access.

Comment: Interesting. So `p` is in an indeterminate state?

Comment: In a manner of speaking. The JVM may very well treat it differently, but the compiler is going to complain when you try to use an unassigned local. You can't say `phone p; if (p.hasPower()) { }`. This is not going to be a `NullPointerReference` at runtime, it will simply be a compile time error.

Answer (score 1):

`Phone p` is a reference to a Phone object which has not been initialised.

`Phone p = new Phone(200)` is a reference to a Phone object which has been initised with the constructor `Phone(int var)`.

`new Phone(200)` creates a new Phone object with the constructor `Phone(int var)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Phone p;
```

is just a reference or a "pointer" as some people liking C language would call it. It contains the path to an object but currently the path is null.

```
Phone p = new Phone(200) //(200 is the price of the phone).
```

Here you are creating a new Phone object, by calling its constructor which takes the 200 value. The object is then assigned to the reference p.

```
new Phone(200)
```

Here you are just creating an Object of type Phone but do not have a reference to it, so this object is in turn to be Garbage Collected by the JVM (if not referenced to something else internally).

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html