# Creating unused instance variables in an Android Service

Tags: android, service, instance-variables

I am developing an Android application that has a Service listening for some events and logging them in the back ground. Since I log several event, I have created a logger class for each type of event I want to log. The following is one such class.

```
public class AccelerometerLogger {

  private final Context mContext;
  private final SensorManager mSensorManager;
  private final Sensor mAccelerometer;
  private final AccelerometerListener mAccelerometerListener;

  public AccelerometerLogger(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mContext = context;
    mSensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    mAccelerometer = getAccelerometer();
    mAccelerometerListener = new AccelerometerListener();
    boolean status = false;
    if (mAccelerometer != null) {
      status = mSensorManager.registerListener(mAccelerometerListener, mAccelerometer,
          SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }
    Log.i("AccelerometerLogger", "Regisrtered = " + status);
  }

  private Sensor getAccelerometer() {
    List<Sensor> sensors = mSensorManager.getSensorList(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    if (sensors.size() > 0) {
      return sensors.get(0);
    }

    return null;
  }

  private class AccelerometerListener implements SensorEventListener {
    long lastTime;
    long now;

    AccelerometerListener() {
      now = lastTime = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
      now = event.timestamp; //timestamp is in nanoseconds
      if (now - lastTime > 5000000000l) {
        // Log some stuff here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, in the onCreate() of the Service I do

```
AccelerometerLogger accelerometerLogger = new AccelerometerLogger(getApplicationContext());
```

But I never need to use accelerometerLogger, since the object implicitly does all the work once constructed, and hangs around as long as the Service does. Although the approach seems to be working for me, there is always a warning for unused local variable. Is there a better way of accomplishing what I want to do?

I appreciate your time to help me.

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: This sounds like a horrible design. You're almost certainly going to be leaking contexts here.

Comment: I am sending the Application Context to the Acclerometer as my updated code says. After all, I want the logger to be alive as long as the application (which is a Service) to be alive. Do you still think it is a horrible design?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your using eclipse you can just stick this above the declaration.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
AccelerometerLogger accelerometerLogger = new AccelerometerLogger();
```

I guess because this annotation is provided, creating unused objects isn't seen as evil or anything. The warnings are really annoying though so it's great they have these kind of annotations.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** following the OP's clarification in the comments that this is being assigned to a field in the service class, rather than a local variable, my answer no longer applies.

---

You can just do

```
new AccelerometerLogger();
```

by itself.

Comment: Doesn't it mean that the logger object is immediately eligible for garbage collection as it says in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314424/difference-between-creating-a-new-object-and-class-objectname)?

Comment: Yes, but it's no different from assigning it to a local variable in your service's `onCreate()` and then never referencing it again. That too is eligible for garbage collection as soon as `onCreate()` finishes. It you want it to have a longer lifetime, it needs to be a field of the class, not just a local variable inside `onCreate()`.

Comment: In deed, I have it as a field in the class extending Service. Sorry for the confusion; the last line of code I wrote was to keep it simple.